# strip out tags except specific ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't find a question that matches my scenario, and can't figure this out for some reason...  jQuery is ok, but native (or angularJS / jQuery Lite) would be preferred.

I have html with several custom tags. I want to keep some tags present (they are empty), but only keep the text of all others. I'm not manipulating DOM directly - I put in an HTML, and need to get out HTML. e.g.:

`<span class="ng-scope">CTAGCTCTCTGGAGATTAACGAGGAGAAATACTAGAtTGGTTCAT</span><start feat="1" class="ng-scope"></start><annotation index="1" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-scope" style="background-color: rgb(238, 153, 238); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"><span tooltip="Another Promoter" tooltip-placement="mouse" tooltip-append-to-body="true" ng-transclude="" class="ng-scope"><span class="ng-scope">GATCATAAgcttgaat</span></span></annotation><end feat="1" class="ng-scope"></end><span class="ng-scope">tagccaaacttatt</span>`

to

`CTAGCTCTCTGGAGATTAACGAGGAGAAATACTAGAtTGGTTCAT <start feat="1"></start> GATCATAAgcttgaat <end feat="1"></end> tagccaaacttatt`

white space not important. Ultimately I'll pulling out the start and ends also, so their form isn't too important (e.g. could be <1> xx )

Thanks

Comment: Why not manipulate *a* DOM? It should be possible to parse the HTML into a DOM fragment and replace the undesired nodes with their `innerText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this does the tag work you need without a dom:

```
var str = IN.value;
var str2= str.replace(/\s*<(\/?)(\w+)([^>]*?)>\s*/g,  function(j,b,a,c){
  return   ({start:1, end:1}[a]) ?   ("<"+b+a+c+">")  : "";
});

var end='CTAGCTCTCTGGAGATTAACGAGGAGAAATACTAGAtTGGTTCAT<start feat="1" class="ng-scope"></start>GATCATAAgcttgaat<end feat="1" class="ng-scope"></end>tagccaaacttatt';

str2==end // true
```

i figured you don't really want/need the class attrib removed, since you didn't mention it.
if you do, then it gets more complicated, but is probably do-able...

Comment: initial example was too contrived, see if the new one makes more sense?

Comment: [Why not to use regex for parsing HTML ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @adeneo: it doesn't need parsed, the code is not html, and this is not a parser... i try to avoid the dom when possible.

Answer (score 0):

HTML should be parsed as HTML, and once you have manipulated the DOM elements, removed what you want etc. you can extract it as a string, like so:

```
var html = 'your HTML string here';

var markup = $.map($('<div />', {html:html}).children(), function(el) {
    return /(start|end)/.test(el.tagName.toLowerCase()) ? el.outerHTML : $(el).text();
}).join('');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bGmFU/)